# Resize Karnaugh Map

Tags: karnaugh

I am trying to create a Karnaugh Map, but I need to have variables as the terms for the K-map. I am using the karnaugh-map package, where I can get the variable terms inside the K-map, but the K-map is too small. I need to resize it so that each term fits within its box.

[image: Small K-Map]

I found this document: https://ctan.mines-albi.fr/graphics/pgf/contrib/karnaugh-map/karnaugh-map.pdf, that says I can resize the K-map with the following code:

```
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{karnaugh-map}
\end{karnaugh-map}%
}
```

I tried using that method to resize my K-map, but when I compile I get an error.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{karnaugh-map}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}
    {
        \begin{karnaugh-map}[2][2][1]
            \manualterms{$A_0'B_0'+A_0B_0$,0,0,$A_0'B_0'+A_0B_0$}
        \end{karnaugh-map}
    }
\end{document}
```

```
❯ tectonic test.tex
Running TeX ...
warning: accessing absolute path `/dev/null`; build may not be reproducible in other environments
error: test.tex:6: Missing number, treated as zero
error: halted on potentially-recoverable error as specified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the manual states, you can't change the relevant dimensions. So one alternative is using `plain Tikz`. Here's one way to do it: there are many more with `Tikz`.

For reference have a look into the [pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/). Most of the statements used here you'll find already in the tutorials of Part 1.

[image: result]

Some hints:

- nodes with style `kd` form the matrix
- their square shape is set via `minimum size`
- here I position them with absolute coordinates

Values 0,1 :

- the `xv` and `yv` styles make sure, the relevant nodes fit bottom-top (south-north) and left-right (east-west)
- it's a kind of shortcut to position them

Labels X1, X2:

- similar approach, using upper right corner of node (A)
- and lower left corner of node (A)
- together with some absolute shift in y-/x-direction, respectively

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    kd/.style={draw, minimum size=2.5cm},
    xv/.style={anchor=south,minimum height=1cm},
    yv/.style={anchor=east,minimum width=1cm},
    xl/.style={anchor=south,yshift=9mm},
    yl/.style={anchor=east,xshift=-9mm},
    ]
    % ~~~ matrix ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[kd] (A)   at (0,0)        {$A_0'B_0'+A_0B_0$};
    \node[kd]       at (2.5,-2.5)   {$A_0'B_0'+A_0B_0$};
    \node[kd] (B)   at (2.5,0)      {$0$};
    \node[kd] (C)   at (0,-2.5)     {$0$};
    % ~~~ values ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[xv] at (A.north) {$0$};
    \node[xv] at (B.north) {$1$};
    \node[yv] at (A.west)  {$0$};
    \node[yv] at (C.west)  {$1$};
    % ~~~ labels ~~~~~~~~~
    \node[xl] at (A.north east) {$X_0$};
    \node[yl] at (A.south west) {$X_1$};
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Some alternatives with Tikz:

- using matrix placement
- using tikzlibrary postioning
- using foreach-loops
- ...

Some alternatives without Tikz:

- using tables of any kind